# WP7 Linq-to-sql query with relation not working

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, linq-to-sql, relation

i have 2 tables: Item and Category with fields (pseudo code):

```
Item
----------
int ItemId
Category Category
(etc...)

Category
----------
string Name
bool IsSelected
(etc...)
```

I would like to retrieve from DB all Items where category has flag IsSelected = true.

For testing first I create Items:

```
Category category = new Category() { Name = "test_name", IsSelected = true };
db.CategoriesTable.InsertOnSubmit(category);
db.SubmitChanges();
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Item item = new Item() { Category = category };
    db.ItemsTable.InsertOnSubmit(item);
}
db.SubmitChanges();
```

Now I have 10 Items with category with IsSelected = true.

When I want to retrieve all Items with category with IsSelected == true, I write:

```
Array<Item> items = ItemsTable.Where(f => f.Category.IsSelected).ToArray();
```

And I expected 10 items, but I got only 1 item - the first one! Why? I checked data in table and every item has the same category, so I guess that query is wrong...

Comment: I think you should write : Array<Item> items = ItemsTable.Where(f => f.Category.IsSelected == true).ToArray();

Comment: Perhaps ItemsTable already is filtered before the query? Anyway, you should have a look at the SQL that is generated that will give you a clue about the correctnes of the query. What happens when you do not filter at all?

Comment: @Pleun

ItemsTable is not filtered before query. Look:

    List<Item> items = db.ItemsTable.Where(f => f.Category.IsSelected).ToList();
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(items.Count);

gives output: 1.  

    List<Item> items2 = db.ItemsTable.ToList();
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(items2.Count);

gives output: 10.

Comment: How can I check the SQL generated by Linq to sql?

Comment: Ok, I figured it out! I made a mistake in class Item at definition of column Category. I didn't define parameters ThisKey, OtherKey and IsForeignKey. Now all works fine